# How do I break out of an R command

Tags: r

I'm simply trying to break out of an R session when I've accidentally entered an incorrect command. Consider this captured text from the the R session:

> json2["]
>   + ""
>   + "
>   Error: unexpected string constant in:
>   """
>   ""

I accidentally typed json["] and the R interpreter sees this as an incomplete command, and it then cycles me through the line continuation prompt, which is a plus '+" symbol, which is not what I want or need.

I then have to try and complete this invalid command to regain control of the console. What I want is a set of keystrokes to break out of this process, similar to a ctrl-c in a terminal session.

Comment: _Esc_ should work.

Comment: If that doesn't do it, ^D is always a solid bet.

Comment: @Zenexer: Did you meant ^C? (Ctrl-D opens up a directory dialog window for me.)

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple (<esc>). Normally, since this is the first thing I usually try. Anyway, that did the trick. ^D does nothing, nor does ^C. I did not use the control key with the escape key. It worked standalone.

Comment: @BondedDust No, ^D is often used to exit programs cleanly or close a stream.  Some programs instead intercept ^C to close cleanly, but traditionally ^C exits immediately, without any cleanup.  As a last resort, ^\\ sends SIGQUIT, which programs rarely bother to intercept.  Even when ^C fails, that'll usually work.  Normally it creates a core dump, too, but they're small and you can usually just ignore them.

Comment: @Zenexer  Probably system and IDE- specific behavior then. ctrl-D does nothing on a Mac (Unix BSD)  R session running in the R.app GUI.  But it is effective when run as a "Terminal session". I'm not exactly sure what keystrokes are intended by "^\\". The ctrl-C and `escape` keystrokes are mentioned in the R documentation. When effective they are supposed to have the same behavior as you described for ctrl-D.